# Yii2 Captcha dosent render and show raw data image

Tags: yii, yii2, gd, captcha

Captcha in backend is configured and has worked.
But with same configuration does not work on front-end and show raw image data, like in the picture.
Access roles are correct and captcha action does not have any additional config. 
PHP GD is already active in my host
**Yii2 Captcha show RAW data**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things you might want to check.

First, did you override the actions() method in your controller class? You'll need to add the following:

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            'captcha' => array(
                'class' => 'CCaptchaAction',
                'backColor' => 0xFFFFFF,
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

If you did that and it still doesn't work, check your controller access. When you are overwritten accessRules(), you need to make the captcha action available for everyone, like this:

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function accessRules() {
        return array('allow', 'actions' => array('captcha'), 'users' => array('*'));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps !.

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_clean();
```

please try before you show captcha or any other suitable place.